# Backbone create a complex tagname view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I konw that i can creat a simply tagname as:

```
          var Home = Backbone.View.extend({

          tagName:"li",
```

but I need to create a complex tagname in my view as:

```
            <div class="row">

            <div class="page-header ">
              <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">see all</a></p>
              <h4>Honors <small>(10)</small></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="pagination-centered">


            </div>

        </div>
```

and append the result of render in div class="pagination-centered".
Can i create a complex tagname like this above?And append render's result in a specific class?

Comment: Was there a question in there?

Comment: I've added question more detailed

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can't. Your view element is only **one** DOM element. What you're showing is several nested elements.
Here your view element should be the parent `div`, and the rest could be appended as a template.

```
var Home = Backbone.View.extend({
  // tagName: 'div' <= useless as it's the default value
  className: 'row',
  template: myHTML,
  render: function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template);
  }
```

});

And btw, it wasn't necessary to create a new question.

Comment: If i create several nested elements with jquery,append it to the dom and after append the render?But inside render how can catch element dom?

Comment: You should do several levels of logic instead (a more generic view, and another more focused). But you could use `View#setElement` and `View#$` to change your element.